# Can recursion done on sets be done in reverse?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

Given the recursive definition below:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Basis Step} &: 3 \in S \\
\text{Recursive Step} &: \{x, y\} \in S \implies (x+y) \in S
\end{align}$$

This means members of the set include:

$$\{3, 3\} = 6 \in S \\
\{6, 3\} = 9 \in S \\
\{9, 3\} = 12 \in S \\
\dots$$

In fact, $\{3a : a \in \mathbb{Z}^+, a \neq 0\} \in S$. But can it be done in reverse? $3 = 1 + 2$, if $3 \in S$, can this mean $\{1, 2\} \in S$ as well, and therefore the members of the set are $\{a : a \in \mathbb{N}\} \in S$?

More declaratively: if $\{x, y\} \in S \implies (x + y) \in S$, does $(x + y) \in S \implies \{x, y\} \in S$?

Comment: Your "Recursive Step" doesn't allow going backward in the way you tried.

Comment: How show $-3 \in S$?

Comment: @coffeemath $3 \in S \implies 6 + (-3) = 3 \implies \{6, -3\} \in S \implies -3 \in S$?

Comment: Knowing that $x, y \in S \implies x + y \in S$ does not automatically imply that $x + y \in S \implies x, y \in S$. If you can prove this for your particular set $S$, then bully for you, but this is not an automatic implication.

Comment: gator-- I don't follow your last comment.

Comment: @coffeemath OP is using the incorrect assumption that if $a\in S$, and $x+y=a$, then $x,y\in S$.

Comment: "$\{a,b\}\in S$" doesn't mean what you're using it for - you either want to say "$a,b\in S$" (which is understood as shorthand for "$a\in S$ and $b\in S$") or "$\{a,b\}\subseteq S$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With notation fixed per my comment, you're asking

> if $\{x, y\} \subseteq S \implies (x + y) \in S$, does $(x + y) \in S \implies \{x, y\} \subseteq S$?

**No, it does not.** For example, take $S$ to be the set of all multiples of $3$; then on the one hand $S$ is closed under sums, but on the other hand  $4+2\in S$ while neither $4$ nor $2$ is in $S$.